# control Kinect motor OPENNI 2

Tags: c++, kinect, openni

I want to control the kinect motor I m working with OPENNI 2.0 , windows7,visual studio C++ 2010.

I found on the web a code to control but It use #include  ( openni 1.x) .
and this file doesn't exist anymore in the OPENNI 2.0 version.
so How could I control the kinect motor on OPENNI2.0 in c++ 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OPENNI 2.0 uses the Microsoft Kinect SDK now, if using OPENNI 2.0 is not mandatory or that you don't want to use this SDK, you can install openni 1.5.4 instead :

1. Install [OpenNI-Win32-1.5.4.0-Dev1.msi](http://www.openni.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/OpenNI-Win32-1.5.4.0-Dev1.zip)
2. Install [SensorKinect093-Bin-Win32-v5.1.2.1.msi](https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect) (in the bin folder)
3. Install [Sensor-Win32-5.1.2.1-Redist.msi](http://www.openni.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Sensor-Win32-5.1.2.1-Redist.zip)
4. Install [NITE-Win32-1.5.2.21-Dev.msi](http://www.openni.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/NITE-Win32-1.5.2.21-Dev.zip)

Take care of the environment variables if you keep the two versions of openni.

Comment: so you suggest that I use OPENNI 2.0 + microsoft SDK to control the motor kinect?

Comment: I think you don't really have the [choice](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a11ff6d9-7fbe-4636-8ff0-92d6220ac3f8/fyi-openni-2-is-available-uses-ms-kinect-sdk-drivers-when-using-kinect-sensor?forum=kinectsdk), after PrimeSense has been bought by Apple recently, maybe this policy will change.